# Stackapps Notification Bar is off-centered

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackapps

I took this picture of the full window chrome in Chrome so that the juxtaposition of the banner across the page shows. I've also included one from math.se (where I knew I wasn't recently logged in) to show the juxtaposition. I have always had this issue on StackApps that I can recall.

[image: Example picture that demonstrates an offset notification bar]
[image: Example picture that demonstrates a correct notification bar]

While I realize this isn't HIGH priority to be fixed, I am curious if others see the problem (for vindication that I'm not losing my mind) and if I recall correctly this is because StackApps doesn't run the "standard SE2.0 setup" (and wanted to verify that).

So in other news ... I'm curious about this SE2.0API beta ;-)

Comment: +1 for the FHC. I am also very curious about the SE2.0API!

Comment: As an aside, there is other theming there that seems to be inconsistent, such as the comment upvote timer warning (I forget what we call it, when you try and upvote two comments in less than 5 seconds)

Comment: Just saw this a few minutes ago.

Comment: @PopularDemand I was told that it was a known issue, and that nobody cares about fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing says "low priority" quite like a fix coming nearly 3 years later.

Comment: Three years?  I think [we've got that beat](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/bug+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-norepro?sort=newest&page=3&pagesize=50).